# Laravel relationship latest - memory limit

Tags: php, laravel, memory, relationship, limit

I have problem with relationship and memory limit. In short I have Machines, Locations and Employees table. Machine hasMany locations and Location belongsTo Employee. Database of machines has 10 rows, locations has around 70k rows and Employees 10 rows. When I try to list machines with last location & employe I get server error. I limit results to 10 rows... 
Code:

```
// Machine.php
public function lastLocation()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Location::class)
                ->latest();
}

// Location.php
public function employee()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class);
}
```

I also tried this:

```
public function lastLocation()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Location::class)
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->limit(1);
}
```

But this didn't help...
I also tried to specify columns to get less data but still the same problem:

```
Machine::->with(['lastLocation' => function($q) {
   $q->select('id', 'employee_id', 'machine_id', 'lat', 'lng', 'created_at')
     ->with(['employee:id,name,surname']);
}])...
```

Question is how to optimize this query? In future there will be millions of rows in Locations table... My memory_limit is 512mb right now and I can't believe it's not enough for this data.

Comment: What is that server error?

Comment: You can do some indexing on machine_id column which is a foreign key in your one to many relationship table.

Comment: just set machine id as the foreign key and the index will automatically be there. More importantly what is the server error? you cant asume withouth knowing the error.

Comment: Ajax call returns empty result. I don't think indexing will solve memory limit. As I know it can only make query faster. It seems like problem is that it's fetching not just latest row from DB but thousands of results

Comment: You have still not told us what the server error is

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error... Nothing else just blank page (ajax call) even when I turn on debug mode

Comment: You can make use of joins to optimize the query, checkout the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins